# quiz program not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to create a quiz program. On click of a button each question object loads to page. I have a code but its not working. Not sure whats wrong. Can anybody please help. I wanna control the loop with with button click so that I get first question and then click and next question and so on.

```js
var quiz = document.quiz;
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');

var questions =
    [
      
      {
        question: "What is the color of skye?",
        choices : ["Blue", "White", "Yellow", "Green"],
        answer  : 0
      },
      
      {
        question: "What is the color of skye?",
        choices : ["Blue", "White", "Yellow", "Green"],
        answer  : 0
      }
    ];

var counter = 0;


  nextButton.onclick = function () {
  while ( counter < questions.length ) {
        
          var question = questions[counter].question;
          var choices = questions[counter].choices;
          var answer = questions[counter].answer;
              answer = choices[answer];
          
          print( question, choices, answer );
          counter++;
       
  }
   };

function print ( question , choices , answer ) {
    
    var html = "";
  
    html += "</h3>" + question + "</h3>";
  
    for ( var option in choices ) {
      
        html += "<input type='radio' name='option'>" + choices[option] + "</input>";
        html += "<br>";
      
    }
  
    quiz.innerHTMl = html;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="quiz"></form>
<form action="" name="controls">
  <input type="button" value="Next" id="nextButton">
</form>
<script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry about the same question objects in the questions array. It supposed to be different questions.

Comment: use console logs / alerts and verify flow and data

Comment: var quiz = document.quiz; What is that? What is document.quiz?

Comment: Its the name of the form i am appending the quiz data to

Comment: Well first bug that I notice is that you have to `<\h3>`. Only one should be closed.
Regarding the question itself, can you use jQuery?

Comment: Jquery is not an option as i have been advised to avoid it until i learn they language itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example of your code  https://jsfiddle.net/r1kcL1pc/

```
quiz.innerHTMl = html;
```

this line must be change in

```
 quiz.innerHTML = html;
```

only a letter :)

Then, I deleted the while cicle, so you can change the question every time you click on the button.

Comment: How can i load the first question on page load?

Comment: hi, here found the code modified to achieve your goal https://jsfiddle.net/r1kcL1pc/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help giuseppe straziota

Comment: I am trying to capture user answer but can't figure it out. Can anyone please help.